# Hide options in dropdown select

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I do not have access to adjust the options within a dropdown. So I want to hide them from the DOM. I am having trouble just hiding the option. Currently I can hide the entire dropdown, if my array consists of the countries I want to hide.

https://jsfiddle.net/gmLa5bgz/

html

```
<select id="country_2">
<option value="AS">American Samoa</option><option value="AD">Andorra</option><option value="AO">Angola</option><option value="AI">Anguilla</option>
</select>
```

JQuery

```
var countries = new Array("France","Germany");
var i = 0;
var countryLength = countries.length;
for(i = 0; i < countryLength; i++) {
$('#country_2').each(function(){
if($(this).text().search(countries[i]) >= 0)
{$(this).remove();};
});
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this out:

```
var countries = new Array("France","Germany");
var i = 0;
var countryLength = countries.length;
for(i = 0; i < countryLength; i++) {
    $('#country_2 option').each(function(){
        if($(this).text()==countries[i])
        {
           $(this).remove();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: This worked and much simpler than what I was trying!